# Stop function after secods

Tags: ios, swift

I have setup and position the CAEmitterLayer. It shows images coming from the emitter.

The code works very well, but I have one problem. I would like to stop snowDribbbleBalls() function after 5 seconds it is called. I appreciate any help lead me to solve the problem.

(Instead of removing sublayers, I would like to simply stop function.)

```
//real code
class CompletedViewController: UIViewController {

                               self.snowDribbbleBalls()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5)) { [weak self] in
                cell.birthRate = 0
                cell2.birthRate = 0
                cell3.birthRate = 0
                cell4.birthRate = 0

            }


}

func snowDribbbleBalls() {

        let emitter = Emitter.get(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ichi"))
        emitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
        emitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(emitter)

        let emitter2 = Emitter.get(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ni"))
        emitter2.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 6, y: 0)
        emitter2.emitterSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(emitter2)

        let emitter3 = Emitter.get(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "san"))
        emitter3.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 1, y: 0)
        emitter3.emitterSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(emitter3)

        let emitter4 = Emitter.get(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "yon"))
        emitter4.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 3.5, y: 0)
        emitter4.emitterSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(emitter3)
    }



class Emitter {
    static func get(with image: UIImage) -> CAEmitterLayer {
        let emitter = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
        emitter.emitterCells = generateEmitterCells(with: image)

        let emitter2 = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitter2.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
        emitter2.emitterCells = generateEmitterCells(with: image)

        let emitter3 = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitter3.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
        emitter3.emitterCells = generateEmitterCells(with: image)

        let emitter4 = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitter4.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
        emitter4.emitterCells = generateEmitterCells(with: image)

        return emitter
    }

    static func generateEmitterCells(with image: UIImage) -> [CAEmitterCell] {
        var cells = [CAEmitterCell]()

        let cell = CAEmitterCell()
        cell.contents = image.cgImage
        cell.birthRate = 30
        cell.lifetime = 50
        cell.velocity = CGFloat(300)
        cell.emissionLongitude = (180 * (.pi/180))
        cell.emissionRange = (14 * (.pi/180))
        cell.scale = 0.25
        cell.scaleRange = 0.3
        ////
        let cell2 = CAEmitterCell()
        cell2.contents = image.cgImage
        cell2.birthRate = 26
        cell2.lifetime = 50
        cell2.velocity = CGFloat(160)
        cell2.emissionLongitude = (180 * (.pi/180))
        cell2.emissionRange = (12 * (.pi/180))
        cell2.scale = 0.25
        cell2.scaleRange = 0.2
        ////
        let cell3 = CAEmitterCell()
        cell3.contents = image.cgImage
        cell3.birthRate = 20
        cell3.lifetime = 50
        cell3.velocity = CGFloat(160)
        cell3.emissionLongitude = (180 * (.pi/180))
        cell3.emissionRange = (16 * (.pi/180))
        cell3.scale = 0.25
        cell3.scaleRange = 0.2
        ////
        let cell4 = CAEmitterCell()
        cell4.contents = image.cgImage
        cell4.birthRate = 27
        cell4.lifetime = 20
        cell4.velocity = CGFloat(260)
        cell4.emissionLongitude = (180 * (.pi/180))
        cell4.emissionRange = (10 * (.pi/180))
        cell4.scale = 0.25
        cell4.scaleRange = 0.2

        cells.append(cell)

        return cells

    }

}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
                    
              self.snowDribbbleBalls()     
                    
        })

if you want to remove this than use removefrom subview

Comment: `snowDribbbleBalls()` will run just a few microseconds, no seconds. In fact do you want stop an animation?

Comment: @ macmoonshine yes I would like to stop animation!

Comment: You can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25120393/2000162 Run with a delay and cancel whenever you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make things clear... The function doesn't 'run' while the layer is emitting, so the real question is *"How to stop the emitter ?"* and the answer to this is by setting the `birthRate` of the emitter layer to zero.

So just hold a reference (since you don't want to be removed) and set the `birthRate` to zero after 5 seconds...

Something like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5)) { [weak self] in
    // self.emitter is declared as
    // var emitter: CAEmitterLayer!
    // and set on `emitter = Emitter.get(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ichi"))`
    self?.emitter.birthRate = 0
}
```

Comment: @risa8 Can you please edit your question and share your code? Because I _did_ try my answer before posting and is working fine...

Comment: Ok give me a second. The error is "Value of CompleteViewController has no member cell2."

Comment: ... so what is `cell2`? It seems that this problem is unrelated to the specific question...

Comment: Sorry mistype it is cell

Comment: I would gladly help you with that, but you have to post some _real_ code in your question. Just hit `Edit` and include the code as it is now if possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149695/discussion-between-alladinian-and-risa8).